# Issue with Promise

Tags: promise, nodes, bluebird

I got a small problem with my function below. The Promise.map doesn't wait for Folder.create to be finished and iterate through the next value.

```js
Promise.map(name, function(na){
  return fs.stat(na.url, function(err, stats){
    if (typeof stats === 'undefined'){
      console.log("file doesn't exist");
      return Folder.create(na).then(function(fd){
        return mkdirp(root + product.url).then(function(){
          console.log("Folder Created");
          return null;
        });
      }, function(err){
        console.log(err);
        return reject({message: "Error when creating the folder"});
      });
    }
  });
}).then(function(){
  console.log('Iteration Done');
  return resolve({message: "Folder Created!"});
});

// I GOT : 
//file doesn't exist
//file doesn't exist
//file doesn't exist
//Iteration Done
//file doesn't exist
//file doesn't exist
//file doesn't exist
//Iteration Done
//Folder Created
//Folder Created
//Folder Created
//Folder Created
//Folder Created
//Folder Created
```

Comment: Can be because of the `if (typeof stats === 'undefined'){` ?

Comment: Unfortunately no , it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple issues here:

1. `Promise.map()` runs the operations for each array element in parallel, not serially.  If you want them run serially, you can pass `{concurrency: 1}` as an option to `Promise.map()` or use `Promise.mapSeries()`.
2. `fs.stat()` does not return a promise so your main callback to `Promise.map()` isn't returning a promise so the whole `Promise.map()` infrastructure does not know how to wait for any of your results.  You can promisify `fs.stat()` to solve that issue.
3. You appear to be using an [anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns) with your `resolve()` and `reject()` calls in here.  You don't show the outer definition where those come from, but you should be just using the promise returned from `Promise.map()` rather than doing that.

Here's how they can successfully be run in parallel:

```
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));

Promise.map(name, function(na){
  return fs.statAsync(na.url).then(function(err, stats){
    if (typeof stats === 'undefined'){
      console.log("file doesn't exist");
      return Folder.create(na).then(function(fd){
        return mkdirp(root + product.url).then(function(){
          console.log("Folder Created");
          return null;
        });
      }, function(err){
        console.log(err);
        return Promise.reject({message: "Error when creating the folder"});
      });
    }
  });
}).then(function(){
  console.log('Iteration Done');
  return ({message: "Folder Created!"});
});
```

If you wanted to run your operations serially with Bluebird, you could pass `{concurrency: 1}` to `Promise.map()`:

```
Promise.map(name, fn, {concurrency: 1}).then(...);
```

Or use:

```
Promise.mapSeries(name, fn).then(...)
```

Comment: In recent Bluebird, you should use `mapSeries`, which also maps in the expected order.

Comment: @Bergi - Added that option.

Comment: @jfriend00 To precise the example i gave, I use Promise.reject to leave the Promise.map loop and come back to the Promise which called this one. Is it not recommended to use that way ?

Comment: @musecz - You don't show your outer code, but a rejected promise will already stop the promise loop and that rejection will propagate upwards to the prior chained promises.

Comment: @jfriend00 Okay thanks. how to you reject a promise with promise.map ? By the way I got this error using statAsync : Unhandled rejection Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory. Do you know how to avoid this error ?

Comment: @musecz - That means the file doesn't exist.  That's what `fs.statAsync()` is telling you.  Do you mean to be doing `fs.stat()` on `na.url`?  That should be used for files, not URLs.

Comment: @jfriend00 What I meant is this error avoid my function to continue.

Comment: @musecz - I don't follow your specific circumstance, but if a promise chain rejects anywhere in the chain, it will abort the chain on its own.  Of, if you're in a `.then()` success handler, you can `throw` or return a rejected promise to abort the chain.

Answer (score 0):

`fs.stat` is a callback type function and thus, does not return a Promise. You should modify your code to be something like this

```
// This might not work directly. I haven't tried to run it
Promise.map(name, function(na) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.stat(na.url, function(err, stats) {
            if (typeof stats === 'undefined') {
                console.log("file doesn't exist");
                Folder.create(na).then(function(fd) {
                    return mkdirp(root + product.url);
                }).then(function() {
                    console.log("Folder Created");
                    resolve();
                }).catch(function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    reject({
                        message: "Error when creating the folder"
                    });
                });
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });
}).then(function() {
    console.log('Iteration Done');
    return {
        message: "Folder Created!"
    };
});
```

Comment: Rather than perpetuate the [anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns) the OP is using, you should just promisify `fs.stat()` so  you aren't mixing plain callbacks and promises.  Anytime, you have a `resolve()` in one arm of a `.then()` handler and a `reject()` in the other arm or in the `.catch()`, you for sure have an anti-pattern and should just be returning a higher level promise.